# Anaphoric list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the following toy example:

```
>>> def square(x): return x*x
... 
>>> [square(x) for x in range(12) if square(x) > 50]
[64, 81, 100, 121]
```

I have to call square(x) twice in the list comprehension. The duplication is ugly, bug-prone (it's easy to change only one of the two calls when modifying the code), and inefficient.

Of course I can do this:

```
>>> squares = [square(x) for x in range(12)]
>>> [s for s in squares if s > 50]
[64, 81, 100, 121]
```

or this:

```
[s for s in [square(x) for x in range(12)] if s > 50]
```

These are both livable, but it feels as though there might be a way to do it all in a single statement without nesting the two list comprehensions, which I know I'll have to stare it for a while next time I'm reading the code just to figure out what's going on. Is there a way?

I think a fair question to ask of me would be what I imagine such syntax could look like. Here are two ideas, but neither feels idiomatic in Python (nor do they work). They are inspired by [anaphoric macros in Lisp](http://community.schemewiki.org/?anaphoric-if).

```
[square(x) for x in range(12) if it > 50]
[it=square(x) for x in range(12) if it > 50]
```

Comment: Just make your inner list-comp a gen-comp instead: `[s for s in (square(x) for x in range(12)) if s > 50]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use a generator:

```
[s for s in (square(x) for x in range(12)) if s > 50]
```

This avoids creating an intermediate unfiltered list of squares.

Comment: This is pretty similar to `[s for s in [square(x) for x in range(12)] if s > 50]` although I hear you about the efficiency, and I think using \() instead of \[] as the inner set of delimiters is a little more readable.

Comment: @kuzzooroo They are called [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) if you want to know more about them.

Comment: @kuzzooroo It's not really similar. I suggest you read about generators to understand why this is far superior.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a comparison of nested generator vs "chained" list comps vs calculating twice

```
$ python -m timeit "[s for n in range(12) for s in [n * n] if s > 50]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[s for s in (x * x for x in range(12)) if s > 50]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[n * n for n in range(12) if n * n > 50]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 usec per loop

$ pypy -m timeit "[s for n in range(12) for s in [n * n] if s > 50]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.211 usec per loop
$ pypy -m timeit "[s for s in (x * x for x in range(12)) if s > 50]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.359 usec per loop
$ pypy -m timeit "[n * n for n in range(12) if n * n > 50]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0834 usec per loop
```

I used `n * n` instead of `square(n)` because it was convenient and removes the function call overhead from the benckmark

TLDR: For simple cases it may be best to just duplicate the calculation.

Comment: Wow - `pypy` really knocks that last expression out of the park! Any insights why it is so much more efficient ?

Comment: @Floris it's probably just very very amenable to JIT: that can be trivially compiled into a machine-code loop without having to worry much about Python semantics, and then the duplicate multiplication is easily factored out as well

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative, using "chained" list comps rather than nested ones:

```
[s for n in range(12) for s in [square(n)] if s > 50]
```

Might be a weird read, though.

Comment: +1 although I was never very comfortable with creating a list and iterating just to make a local binding. I wish there was a better syntax for it. It's slower than the genexp for cpython, but faster for pypy

Answer (score 3):

```
[square(s) for s in range(12) if s >= 7]  # sqrt(50) = 7.071...
```

Or even simpler (no branching, woo!)

```
[square(s) for s in range(7, 12)]  # sqrt(50) = 7.071...
```

Comment: Why not `range(7, 12)`?

Comment: i think the example is contrived to the point where, though this may be correct, it probably is not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I was going to give this answer but you beat me to it. While this is not what the OP was asking (as a general structure) this does make a valid point - if you can compute the limits, you don't call `square` unneccesarily. But instead of `7`, write `sqrt(50)` - namely the inverse of `square`.

Comment: @Floris: I considered using `sqrt(50)`, but that would compute `sqrt` multiple times, which would be inefficient as compared to computing it just the once

Comment: Would it? I suspect that since it's a constant it would be evaluated just once. Maybe I'm spoilt by clever C compilers...

Comment: @Floris: It actually does. I just checked it with a wrapper around `math.sqrt` that also printed to stdout. I ended up getting a bunch of garbage printed to the console as a result. It kinda makes sense, since the expression might itself be a function of `x`, which would make it dynamic and would therefore have to be eval'd every time. Also, python's not compiled immediately, which would make it far less "intelligent" than those beautiful C compilers

Comment: Yeah - I just tried it too. Using `math.sqrt(50)` instead of `7` slowed things down by about 2x... Well - I have learnt "my new thing for the day". I can go have a beer and some dinner now...

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: I'm blind, duplicated [Eevee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20085243/239657).*

It is possible to abuse iteration over a 1-element list to "bind" intermediate variables:

```
[s for x in range(12) for s in [square(x)] if s > 50]
```

I'm hesitant to recommend this as a readable solution though.

Pro: Compared to the nested comprehension, I prefer the order here — having `for x in range(12)` outside.  You can just read it sequentially instead of zooming in then back out...

Con: The `for s in [...]` is a non-idiomatic hack and might give readers a pause.  The nested comprehension while arguably harder to decipher at least uses language features in an "obvious" way.

- Idea: Renaming the intermediate variable something like `tmp` could I think make it clearer.

The bottom line is that I'm not happy with either.
Probably the most readable is naming the intermediate generator:

```
squares = (square(x) for x in range(12))
result = [s for s in squares if s > 50]
```

*[Side note: naming results of generator expressions is a bit rare.  But read [David Beazley's lecture](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) and it might grow on you.]*

OTOH if you're going to write such constructs a lot, go for the `for tmp in [expr(x)]` pattern — it will become "locally idiomatic" within your code and once familiar, its compactness will pay off.  My readability concern is more about one-off use...